# Spring Data MongoDB field projection problems

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use spring data mongodb repository like this

```
public interface StringFieldSelectRepository extends MongoRepository<String, ObjectId> {

@Query(value="{}", fields="{'key':1}")
    Collection<String> allKeys();
}
```

My Document spec like this...

```
{
    _id : 1236f9391239,
    key : "aa77mykeys",
    name : "myname",
    num : 389
}
```

I intend to extract only key field. I want return like this when I call allKeys();

```
["myKey1","myKey2","etc"...]
```

Is it impossible? Thanks for your help

Comment: How is your output currently ?

Comment: Exception occured, Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.String